# Installing Ubuntu on VMPlayer

Tags: installation, vmware

I am a newbie to VMPlayer and Ubuntu. I have downloaded the VMPlayer version 5.x and ubuntu iso file and the install completes but the GUI is not launching ,the unity mode is not working and when I try to installVMwareTools it gives me the message saying "make sure you are logged in to guest operating system.Mount the virtual CD drive in guest , launch a terminal and use tar to uncompress installer".

Any suggestions? I have tried to do the same with VMPLayer 6.x as well no luck. Some forums I saw that it will automatically launch a firefox nothing happens in my case. Also this the error in the log

```
013-10-11T22:43:59.398-04:00| vcpu-0| I120: TOOLS INSTALL 'C:\Program Files\linux.iso' not present or not readable
2013-10-11T22:43:59.399-04:00| vcpu-0| I120: Msg_Post: Warning
2013-10-11T22:43:59.399-04:00| vcpu-0| I120: [msg.tools.inaccessible] Unable to install VMware Tools. An error occurred while trying to access image file "C:\Program Files\linux.iso" needed to install VMware Tools: The system cannot find the file specified.
2013-10-11T22:43:59.399-04:00| vcpu-0| I120+ If your product shipped with the VMware Tools package, reinstall VMware Player, then try again to install the VMware Tools package in the virtual machine.
```

Comment: Is your host Windows? Why are you trying to look for the iso in the Program Files directory? Could you be more verbose about what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you posted it is searching for linux.iso in "C:\Program Files\linux.iso". Your iso should be in a directory deeper, inside the vmwareplayer folder or whereever you installed vmwareplayer. You will need to click the cd icon on your VMware player screen and browse for the iso file yourself. Then you can proceed with the VMware Player Tools installation proceedure.